# Multivariable Calculus orthogonal curves question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is the problem I am working on from my textbook:

Let y: $R->R^n$ be a differentiable curve. Show that if |y(t)| is constant if and only if y(t) and y'(t) are orthogonal.

What I have so far is the forward direction. If y(t) is constant, then its derivative is the n-dimensional zero vector, which is orthogonal to any other vector in $R^n$.

Now the other direction is what is confusing me, If f(x) and f'(x) are orthogonal, and so have a dot product of 0, then f(x) is a constant function. Any hints or suggestions or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $|y|$ is constant if and only if $|y|^2$ is constant. This helps because $|y|^2=y\cdot y$, which is easier to differentiate...

Comment: Are you sure about your proof of the forward direction? $|y(t)|$ constant isn’t the same as $y(t)$ constant. Consider $y: t\mapsto\left<\cos t,\sin t\right>$, for instance.

Comment: neither (cos(t),sin(t) or (|sin(t)| or |cos(t)|) is are constant functions so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @JamesDickens - by definitiion, $|y| = \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2 +... +y_n^2}$. So $|y|$ can be constant without $y$ being constant. For amd's example, $|y| = \sqrt{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t} = 1$.

Comment: Oh ok i was confusing the symbol for absolute value.